TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colors') Jest Problem

My accordion-item.jsx

import React, {useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Animated, {
  Easing,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {ThemeContext} from 'styled-components';

import {DownArrowIcon} from '#assets/svg';

import {Box, Text} from './atoms';

const AnimatedBox = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Box);

export default function AccordionItem({question, answer, isExpanded, toggleAccordion}) {
  const {
    colors: {text},
  } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0);
  const height = useSharedValue(0);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    height: interpolate(height.value, [0, 1], [0, textHeight]),
  }));

  const animatedArrowStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: `${interpolate(height.value, [0, 1], [0, 180])}deg`,
      },
    ],
  }));

  const handleTextHeight = useCallback(e => setTextHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isExpanded) {
      height.value = withTiming(1, {
        duration: 250,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1),
      });
    } else {
      height.value = withTiming(0, {
        duration: 250,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1),
      });
    }
  }, [isExpanded, textHeight]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} key={question} onPress={toggleAccordion}>
      <Box
        alingItems="center"
        marginY={20}
        width="95%"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        flexDirection="row">
        <Text lineHeight="22px" fontSize={16}>
          {question}
        </Text>
        <AnimatedBox
          position="absolute"
          right="-20px"
          width={24}
          height={24}
          style={animatedArrowStyle}>
          <DownArrowIcon width={24} color={text} height={24} />
        </AnimatedBox>
      </Box>
      <AnimatedBox style={animatedStyle} overflow="hidden">
        <Box position="absolute" bottom="0" left="0" onLayout={handleTextHeight}>
          <Text key={answer} lightFont marginBottom={20} lineHeight="22px" fontSize={15}>
            {answer}
          </Text>
        </Box>
      </AnimatedBox>
      <Box borderBottomWidth={1} borderColor="faqBorderColor" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

AccordionItem.propTypes = {
  question: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  answer: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  isExpanded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleAccordion: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


My test file

import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components/native';
import AccordionItem from '../accordion-item';

// Mock ThemeContext
const theme = {
  colors: {
    text: '#3e3e3e',
    faqBorderColor: '#ccc',
  },
};

describe('AccordionItem', () => {
  it('renders correctly when expanded', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AccordionItem
          question="What is React Native?"
          answer="React Native is a framework for building native apps using React."
          isExpanded={true}
          toggleAccordion={jest.fn()}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders correctly when not expanded', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AccordionItem
          question="What is React Native?"
          answer="React Native is a framework for building native apps using React."
          isExpanded={false}
          toggleAccordion={jest.fn()}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});


This is console output

Console

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <AccordionItem> component:

          at question (C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\src\components\accordion-item.jsx:20:40)
          at useContext (C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\styled-components\src\models\ThemeProvider.js:48:22)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      14 | describe('AccordionItem', () => {
      15 |   it('renders correctly when expanded', () => {
    > 16 |     const tree = renderer.create(
         |                           ^
      17 |       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      18 |         <AccordionItem
      19 |           question="What is React Native?"

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8661:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8694:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4092:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4113:9)
      at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13232:13)
      at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14330:9)
      at commitLayoutEffects_begin (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14316:7)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14301:3)
      at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16062:5)
      at commitRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15933:5)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15454:3)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:16:27)

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <AccordionItem> component:

          at question (C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\src\components\accordion-item.jsx:20:40)
          at useContext (C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\styled-components\src\models\ThemeProvider.js:48:22)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      28 |
      29 |   it('renders correctly when not expanded', () => {
    > 30 |     const tree = renderer.create(
         |                           ^
      31 |       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      32 |         <AccordionItem
      33 |           question="What is React Native?"

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8661:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8694:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4092:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4113:9)
      at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13232:13)
      at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14330:9)
      at commitLayoutEffects_begin (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14316:7)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14301:3)
      at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16062:5)
      at commitRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15933:5)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15454:3)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:30:27)

  ● AccordionItem › renders correctly when expanded
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colors')                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      20 | export default function AccordionItem({question, answer, isExpanded, toggleAccordion}) {                                                                                                                              
      21 |   const {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    > 22 |     colors: {text},                                                                                                                                                                                                   
         |     ^
      23 |   } = useContext(ThemeContext);
      24 |
      25 |   const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0);

      at colors (src/components/accordion-item.jsx:22:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6351:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9855:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:16:27)

  ● AccordionItem › renders correctly when not expanded

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colors')

      20 | export default function AccordionItem({question, answer, isExpanded, toggleAccordion}) {
      21 |   const {
    > 22 |     colors: {text},
         |     ^
      23 |   } = useContext(ThemeContext);
      24 |
      25 |   const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0);

      at colors (src/components/accordion-item.jsx:22:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6351:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9855:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:30:27)

Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js
  ● AccordionItem › renders correctly when expanded

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colors')

      20 | export default function AccordionItem({question, answer, isExpanded, toggleAccordion}) {
      21 |   const {
    > 22 |     colors: {text},
         |     ^
      23 |   } = useContext(ThemeContext);
      24 |
      25 |   const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0);

      at colors (src/components/accordion-item.jsx:22:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6351:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9855:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:16:27)

  ● AccordionItem › renders correctly when not expanded

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colors')

      20 | export default function AccordionItem({question, answer, isExpanded, toggleAccordion}) {
      21 |   const {
    > 22 |     colors: {text},
         |     ^
      23 |   } = useContext(ThemeContext);
      24 |
      25 |   const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = useState(0);

      at colors (src/components/accordion-item.jsx:22:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6351:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9855:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
      at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2576:5)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14910:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17770:5)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18510:3)
      at Object.create (src/components/__test__/accordion-item.test.js:30:27)

Even though I mocked the theme, I get such an error and I'm stuck at this stage. I'm quite new to writing tests with Jest, so I'm waiting for your help. How can I solve this problem? If you can explain in detail what is causing it, it would be a great help to me, thank you.
